What is Gwen doing at Miles Morales’s residence after being expelled from the Spider-Society?
Miles, having escaped the Spider-Society, landed in Earth-42 without realizing it was
the wrong dimension. He revealed his Spider-Man identity to Rio Morales, who didn’t take
him seriously. Meanwhile, Gwen, who was expelled from the Spider-Society, arrived on Earth-1610
and was seen hiding near Miles’ residence:

What is Gwen doing at Miles Morales’s residence after being expelled from the Spider-Society?

#WhatIsStalking

Where else is she to go?

She's looking for Miles.
After she goes into his bedroom and before Rio and Jeff catch her, her spider-sense tells her that Miles isn't on Earth-1610, he's on Earth-42.
It's after that, that she goes to 616B and recruits Peter B Parker.
